# Convert a html div into image

Tags: image, html, canvas

Below is the code that I want to convert to div.
I tried html2canvas but that did not worked somehow.
The div's uppelayer middlerlayer and bottomlayer are one above other making 3 layers.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="bottomLayer">

        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSivV5yARSKfCsfaFmdo1Iwc7muglbp92befBPfS7XxglZ0XrpU" id="preview2" />
    </div>

    <div id="mediumLayer">
        <img src="http://f0.pepst.com/c/B7F2F3/402463/ssc3/home/038/amazing.beauties/diana_penty_02_12x92.jpg_480_480_0_64000_0_1_0.jpg" id="preview" />
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <img src="http://f0.pepst.com/c/B7F2F3/402463/ssc3/home/038/amazing.beauties/diana_penty_02_12x92.jpg_480_480_0_64000_0_1_0.jpg" id="jcrop_target" />
    </div>  

    <div id="upperlayer"><canvas id="canvas2"></canvas></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your goal converting an `img` to a block element (which acts more or less like `div`)? You could try adding a `style="display: block;"` attribute to img: `<img src="..." style="display: block;" alt="..." />`.

Comment: Need some more information - what exactly do you mean by "convert to div"?